# Should I close a "use JavaScript for Java" question?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

In https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7592918/how-to-deploy-dojo-into-pre-existing-project-in-eclipse it looks like the user wants to use a JavaScript toolkit inside a Java project.

- Should I vote to close it? (Java is not JavaScript!)
- If so, what would the correct category be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Donal Fellows says, if you are writing a web application with Java, you can be interested in using Dojo for it.

Anyway, Java is not the relevant part in the question; the relevant part is that the OP is asking help to start using Dojo ("Can anyone help me starting with Dojo?"). [The FAQ has a section about that](https://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask), where it is clearly stated:

> Your questions should be reasonably scoped. If you can imagine an entire book that answers your question, you’re asking too much.

In this case, the question is too generic, and an entire book would answer the question (I can imagine a book titled *Dojo for beginners*). If the OP had a more specific question, e.g. "How can I accomplish this using Dojo?" that would be fine.

As for the closing reason, the "not a real question" reason says, "This question is ambiguous, **vague**, **incomplete**, **overly broad**, or rhetorical and cannot be reasonably answered in its current form."

Answer (score 2):

It's a poorly-asked question right now, but it could be technically coherent (Java webapp serving up pages containing Javascript… that makes sense). See whether you can extract enough information from the asker to make it better first.

Or vote to close for being badly asked (it's missing a lot of vital info). That's an entirely reasonable thing to do.

Answer (score 0):

One vote doesn't close a question. If it's a bad question, don't be afraid to vote to close. If it deserves to stay open, it almost certainly won't accumulate five close votes.

Many questions that **should** be closed *don't* accumulate five close votes, so you should be erring on the side of voting to close.

Comment: If you don't think it should be closed, you should never vote on the assumption that others will disagree. At best, that's just pointless! What reason would he have to close such a question?

Comment: @Shog9 If it's a _bad question_, which shows little effort / is generally unclear, and you're _on the fence_, err on the side of voting to close. Not if it's a good question, or if you think it should stay open.

Comment: You still haven't answered missingno (and my) question: what reason should be used for this? It's not enough to say, "question sucks - close it" - that's enough to *down-vote* but not close. If the question is unclear, nonconstructive, etc. then that's a different matter.

Comment: @Shog9 kiamlaluno's answer covered the second half of the question, the close reason. I was addressing the first half, whether or not to vote to close when it's borderline whether or not the question should be kept. This particular question was clearly borderline in missingno's mind, since he asked whether or not to vote to close.